# Is a tetrahedral complex with two symmetric bidentate ligands optically active?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, stereochemistry

If the shape of of a complex $\ce{M(AA)2}$ (with $\ce{AA}$, a bidentate ligand) is tetrahedral, then is it optically active?

Currently I know that it is optically inactive, but I want to know the reason for this. About which plane is this symmetrical?

Comment: The plane which passes through two A and between the other two A, for example.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin please elaborate your reasoning

Comment: To OP: you should use `$\ce{...}$` specifically for *chemical formulae*. Plain dollar signs `$...$` are to be used for *mathematical expressions*. What's the difference? Well, for one, the former is upright and the latter italics. Upright $\ce{I}$ `$\ce{I}$` is the symbol for iodine, but italics $I$ `$I$` represents something else entirely, like inertia, nuclear spin, or the identity matrix. Please read: [FAQ: How can I format math/chemistry expressions on Chemistry Stack Exchange?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86/16683) for more information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get in contact with other (more senior) students/TA's/your instructor and get access to a molecule kit ([an example](https://www.maruzen.info/hgs/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=654), no affiliation) to build a model of these complexes.  If you can't, use small cubes cut of a potatoes (as atoms) and toothpicks (as bonds).  Then build these complexes.

An idealized representation of a tetrahedral complex around a central ion with two bidentate ligands is shown in the animation below: carbon atoms in black, nitrogen in blue, the transition metal in ocher:

[image]

As mentioned by `@Ivan`, it is possible to define a plane across two atoms of nitrogen and the central ion to bisect the molecule in hemispheres like a mirror.  A second one is just $90^\circ{}$ to the one shown, too.  Whenever you identify at least one of such a mirror plane *across the whole molecule*, the complex/the molecule/the object is *achiral*.  And if a molecule is achiral, it is not optical active.  In your study of chemistry, you are going to encounter this later on again with [*meso compounds*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meso_compound) in organic chemistry, e.g., [tartaric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tartaric_acid).

For the sake of clarity of the representation, I omitted to display the hydrogen atoms.  Second, independent of the former, was to a *assume* the five membered rings as flat.  While such a [conformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformational_isomerism) is not much likely,
it may be -- depending on what you aim to highlight in [molecular symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_symmetry) -- a permissible simplification.

(A nice approach to train oneself recognizing symmetry in molecules is, beside using molecule kits, the set of pages around [Symmetry@Otterbein](https://symotter.org/).)

Comment: Your animation was was very helpful...